# MySQL INSERT INTO query column value equals another SQL SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql

Could anybody kindly guide me on correct direction for below query? It's not working under phpMyAdmin.

```
INSERT INTO `Setting` 
(`id`, `type`, `name`, `value`, `parentId`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `createdById`, `updatedById`) 
VALUES 
(NULL, 0, 'howItWorks', 'Some URL', NULL, NULL, NULL, -1, NULL), 
(NULL, 0, 'howItWorksThumb', 'Some URL', (SELECT id FROM Setting WHERE name = 'howItWorks'), NULL, NULL, -1, NULL);
```

Same kind of query works under PostgreSQL.

**Error I am getting:** #1093 - You can't specify target table 'Setting' for update in FROM clause

**Question is update to explained issues related to LAST_INSERT_ID() solutions:**

To use LAST_INSERT_ID() solutions; child row should be inserting immediately after parent row.

I want to get the parentId for child row not immediately after I insert parent row. What will be the solution?

Also what if I want to add two children for same parent row?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'Setting' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Insert into select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't allow you to `SELECT` in a subquery from the same table that you're inserting into in the main query. So you'll need to split this into two `INSERT` queries:

You can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the auto-increment ID that was assigned in the last `INSERT`, rather than using a subquery.

```
INSERT INTO `Setting` (`id`, `type`, `name`, `value`, `parentId`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `createdById`, `updatedById`) 
    VALUES (NULL, 0, 'howItWorks', 'Some URL', NULL, NULL, NULL, -1, NULL);
INSERT INTO `Setting` (`id`, `type`, `name`, `value`, `parentId`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `createdById`, `updatedById`) 
    VALUES (NULL, 0, 'howItWorksThumb', 'Some URL', LAST_INSERT_ID(), NULL, NULL, -1, NULL);
```

Unfortunately, using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` still doesn't allow you to combine them into a single query, because it calls the function before doing any inserts.

If you're doing the second insert later, you can do it with a normal `INSERT ... SELECT ...`:

```
INSERT INTO `Setting` (`id`, `type`, `name`, `value`, `parentId`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `createdById`, `updatedById`) 
SELECT NULL, 0, 'howItWorksThumb', 'Some URL', id, NULL, NULL, -1, NULL
FROM Setting
WHERE name = 'howItWorks'
```

Comment: But if I want to add the parentId later, not immediately after I insert parent row, what will be the solution?

Comment: Added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, type TINYINT NOT NULL
, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
, value VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
, parentId INT NULL
, createdById INT NOT NULL
);
```

It would be sensible to bind the following into a transaction.

```
INSERT INTO my_table 
( type
, name
, value
, createdById
) 
VALUES 
( 0
, 'howItWorks'
, 'Some URL'
, -1
);

INSERT INTO my_table 
( type
, name
, value
, parentId
, createdById
)
SELECT 0
     , 'howItWorksThumb'
     , 'Some URL'
     , LAST_INSERT_ID()
     , -1
  FROM my_table;
```

End of transaction

```
  SELECT * FROM my_table;
  +----+------+-----------------+----------+----------+-------------+
  | id | type | name            | value    | parentId | createdById |
  +----+------+-----------------+----------+----------+-------------+
  |  1 |    0 | howItWorks      | Some URL |     NULL |          -1 |
  |  2 |    0 | howItWorksThumb | Some URL |        1 |          -1 |
  +----+------+-----------------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: But if I want to add the parentId later, not immediately after I insert parent row, what will be the solution? To use LAST_INSERT_ID() child should be immediately after parent row. What if I want to add two children for same parent row?

Answer (score -1):

see the data type of the table that you created. and see also DEFAULT on the field that you create. If ID is NULL should DEFAULT = auto_increment.

Comment: It is not the problem, please read the subject, column value will be another SQL SELECT query "(SELECT id FROM Setting WHERE name = 'howItWorks')"